# Need to count the number of line breaks

Tags: xslt, break

I'm using this code to make breaks in a XML string every 150 characters.

```
<xsl:variable name="val_cr_ln" select=" '&#xA;' " />
```

I need to do a count of each time this variable occurs.

Can someone tell me how I would do that?

Thanks

Comment: <xsl:variable name="val_cr_ln" select=" '&#xA;' " />

Comment: Are you just looking to count the number of times "val_cr_ln" occurs in an XML document?

Comment: @Steve Rogers: Are you using any kind of XML parsing utility?

Comment: no, I need to include the count of line breaks i send in the footer.

Comment: Seeing your complete XSLT would help. It is not clear what are you asking (at least not clear to me) - to count how many LFs there are in a string, or to modify your XSLT so that it keeps a counter of how many time it inserts the `val_cr_ln` variable.

Comment: In the footer I's sending to vendor I want to provide then number of lines. to detemrine that, I'm looking at the number of times the varible occurs.   That variable is <xsl:variable name="val_cr_ln" select=" '&#xA;' " />

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of times a particular string occurs in the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exslstr="http://exslt.org/strings"
>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name='xml_as_str'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
        </xsl:variable>
        <p>There are <xsl:value-of select='count(exslstr:split($xml_as_str, "string")) - 1' /> occurrences of "string" in there source XML.</p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can be run here: http://www.xmlplayground.com/7QAvNp

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XPath one-liner**:

```
string-length(/) - string-length(translate(string(/), $vNL, ''))
```

**This evaluates to the total number of NL characters in the concatenation of all text-nodes in the XML document**.

**Explanation**:

`translate(string(/), $vNL, '')` produces from the string value of the document node (concatenation of all text-nodes in the XML document) another string, in which any NL character has been replaced by the empty string (deleted).

**Then, subtracting this from the total string-length, gives us exactly the number of the (deleted) NL characters**.

**Here is a complete code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNL" select="'&#x0A;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "string-length(/)
  - string-length(translate(string(/), $vNL, ''))
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<text>
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and surveillance were
extremely tight in Washington, DC, last January. But as George W. Bush prepared to
take the oath of office, security planners installed an extra layer of protection: a
prototype software system to detect a biological attack. The U.S. Department of
Defense, together with regional health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed
a special patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and even aid
stations along the parade route and at the inaugural balls. Software quickly
analyzed complaints of seven key symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for
patterns that might indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at military clinics.
Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — the flu.
</text>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
12
```